Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Services while using System.ServiceModel in release mode
When codes are compiled in debug mode, no error. When compiled with release mode, got the following error
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializerContract.CanSerialize(Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(Type type, String defaultNamespace, XmlSerializerImplementation& contract)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerHelper.FromMappingsViaReflection(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerHelper.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.CreateSerializersFromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)

I use System.ServiceModel v4.10.3 and Service Reference to call and external SOAP service.
Sorry, I could not provide code snapshot...
